# ASP.NET/Paypal: PayPal Integration Wizard?

Tags: asp.net, paypal, integration, implementation, wizard

I'm currently trying my luck to integrate PayPal in ASP.NET (I'm just starting to know more about PayPal, okay?)

[PayPal Integration Wizard.](http://bit.ly/9lmt1e) Hmmm. Does this even work?

What are your thoughts/comments/suggestions about it?
Any good implementation (in ASP.NET) you could share?

Comment: The wizard looks OK, but it depends what you want, really. I'd suggest having a look at the API documentation (https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks). Working with the PayPal APIs is pretty simple...