# Integrating .net app with payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

Hi I want to integrate my .net MVC application with payment gateway PAYPAL. From what I have learnt by far is that ,there must be seller and buyers a/c.
Does that mean that buyers who don't have a/c registered with PAYPAL cannot  do payment with it.

Can someone provide me the link or coding on how to integrate it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET/Paypal: PayPal Integration Wizard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776232/asp-net-paypal-paypal-integration-wizard)

Answer (score 0):

```
Does that mean that buyers who don't have a/c registered with PAYPAL cannot do payment with it.
```

No. if your customers haven't paypal account, they can use their credit card for the payment.

Read this [article](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/43962-How-integrate-PayPal-ASP.NET.aspx). It'll be helpful to you.